# How to add a new attribute to a model (ActiveRecord) in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new on Ruby on Rails and I'm simply trying to add a new attribute to an existing model. I have to add a new boolean attribute to my class that inherits from:

```
ActiveRecord::Base
```

Would someone explain, step by step, how to do it?

Comment: Are you asking how to add a **column** to the **database**? Read about [database migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html). In particular, you can use `add_column` or `change_table(:table_name) { ... }`

Comment: Standard model attributes are defined dynamically, based on the column names in the table. By adding a table column you will have access to the getter/setter methods on the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use migrations in order to add fields to a database. The easiest way to create these files is with a terminal command, however they can be created manually:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Every time you add a migration, you will need to apply it to your database, which is done with:

```
rake db:migrate
```

When you run this, rails go through all your migration files checks which have been applied, and then runs through the rest in order. This means you can roll back migrations that you've screwed up, and can look at the database in different 'stages' of migration if needed.

In your case, we want to add say a field of 'published' to our model 'Book'. We would run from terminal:

```
rails g migration addPublishedToBook published:boolean
```

You can see the structure from above. If we wanted to add a string called firstname to our model User:

```
rails g migration addFirstnameToUser firstname:string
```

After you run these tasks from terminal, each one will create a new migration file. When you're ready, run rake db:migrate, and the new changes will be applied to your database.

Comment: Oh thank you!!! 
When i run rake db:migrate my new field "published" will be accessible from my model "Book" ?? Or i have to do something else?
Thank you again

Comment: That's right - after you have run rails g migration from terminal, check in your directory: app/db/migrate and you should see your migration file. When it is in there, run rake db:migrate from the terminal, and it will apply that to your database

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a new migration specifying the attribute and model which it corresponds:

```
$ rails generate migration add_new_attribute_to_model new_attribute:type
```

This will generate a migration like:

```
class AddNewAttributeToModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[RailsVersion]
  def change
    add_column :model, :new_attribute, :boolean # boolean type attribute
  end
end
```

Then you can persist the changes:

```
$ rails db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Only you need to add a new migration file to make changes to the database.

```
rails g migration AddFieldToMyTable my_field:string
```

Now, you need to persist the change:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

If you want to add the field to the form, do not forget to add the new field in the attributes accepted by the controller:

```
def model_params
  params.require(:model).permit(...., :my_field)
end
```

Simple explained that is the process, I hope it has helped you! (Google traductor love :[)